# Android Studio con sql server debo contratar un Servidor

Tags: android, sql-server

Soy nuevo en android studio, estoy desarrollando una app donde cada usuario va a actualizar y todos los demas tienen que tener la opción de poder ver esos datos.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente tengo que contratar un servidor que tenga sql server o puedo contratar una pagina web que tenga sql y ahí apuntar mi app?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes usar Firebase para manejar el inicio de sesión, base de datos, etc.